# Let $R$ be a ring satisfying $(xy)^3=xy$ for all $x,\, y\in R$. Then $R$ is commutative.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring satisfying $(xy)^3=xy$ for all $x,\, y\in R$. Then $R$ is commutative. Any suggestion how to prove it?

Comment: Do you know how the proof goes in case $R$ is unital?

Comment: I don't think this is an exact duplicate. The ring might have no unit element.

Comment: @azimut  possible duplicate, I agree with Chris. See e.g. the answer of Ehsan M. Kermani, where he/she writes Re-posting it from here. Note that R is not necessarily unital.

Comment: Since we are not in the habit of mentally adding hypotheses to trivialize questions: not a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

An answer is the proof of Theorem 15 from

http://archive.maths.nuim.ie/staff/sbuckley/Papers/bm_variations.pdf